# Optimizing boolean logic tree evaluation

Tags: java, optimization, boolean-logic, bytecode-manipulation

I've got a lot of true/false results saved as bits in `long[]` arrays. I do have a huge number of these (millions and millions of longs).

For example, say I have only five results, I'd have:

```
+----- condition 5 is true
|
|+---- condition 4 is false
||
||+--- condition 3 is true
|||
|||+-- condition 2 is true
||||
||||+- condition 1 is false
10110
```

I also do have a few trees representing statements like:

```
condition1 AND (condition2 OR (condition3 AND condition 4))
```

The trees are very simple but very long. They basically look like this (it's an oversimplification below, just to show what I've got):

```
class Node {    
    int operator();
    List<Node> nodes;
    int conditionNumber();    
}
```

Basically either the Node is a leaf and then has a condition number (matching one of the bit in the long[] arrays) or the Node is not a leaf and hence refers several subnodes.

They're simple yet they allow to express complicated boolean expressions. It works great.

So far so good, everything is working great.  However I do have a problem: I need to evaluate a *LOT* of expressions, determining if they're true or false. Basically I need to do some brute-force computation for a problem for which there's no know better solution than brute-forcing.

So I need to walk the tree and answer either `true` or `false` depending on the content of the tree and the content of the `long[]`.

The method I need to optimize looks like this:

```
boolean solve( Node node, long[] trueorfalse ) {
   ...
}
```

where on the first call the `node` is the root node and then, obviously, subnodes (being recursive, that `solve` method calls itself).

Knowing that I'll only have a few trees (maybe up to a hundred or so) but millions and millions of `long[]` to check, what steps can I take to optimize this?

The obvious recursive solution passes parameters (the (sub)tree and the long[], I could get rid of the `long[]` by not passing it as a parameter) and is quite slow with all the recursive calls etc. I need to check which operator is used (AND or OR or NOT etc.) and there's quite a lot of if/else or switch statements involved.

I'm not looking for another algorithm (there aren't) so I'm not looking for going from O(x) to O(y) where y would be smaller than x.

What I'm looking for is *"times x"* speedup: if I can write code performing 5x faster, then I'll have a 5x speedup and that's it and I'd be very happy with it.

The only enhancement I see as of now --and I think it would be a huge *"times x"* speedup compared to what I have now-- would be to generate bytecode for every tree and have the logic for every tree hardcoded into a class.  It should work well because I'll only ever have a hundred or so trees (but the trees aren't fixed: I cannot know in advance how the trees are going to look like, otherwise it would be trivial to simply hardcode manually every tree).

Any idea besides generating bytecode for every tree?

Now if I want to try the bytecode generation route, how should I go about it?

Comment: For the curious, my Node implementation is not unlike this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830925

Comment: One obvious thing is short-circuiting as soon as possible (e.g. FALSE AND anything is FALSE and TRUE OR anything is TRUE).  I'm assuming you are doing that already?

Comment: @Jeff Foster: yup yup I'm doing it :)  But there can be relatively big trees which are made of a lot of OR statements and only a few ANDs, so even using short-circuiting I'd still like to improve this. :)

Comment: If you think precompiling the tree into bytecode is viable, just go the full length and generate machine instructions (in C, using JNI). The bool only domain is sufficiently simple in assembly to make this risk/benefit trade off work, IMHO

Comment: Are you evaluating the same tree with more than one set of values?

Answer (score 4):

In order to maximize the opportunities for shortcut evaluation, you need to do your own branch prediction.

You might want to profile it, tallying

- which AND branches evaluate into false
- which OR branches result into true

You can then reorder the tree relative to the weights that you found in the profiling step. If you want/need to be particularly nifty, you can devise a mechanism that detects the weighting for a certain dataset during runtime, so you can reorder the branches on the fly.

Note that in the latter case, it might be advisable to not reorder the actual tree (with respect to storage efficiency *and* correctness of result while still executing), but rather devise a tree-node visitor (traversal algorithm) that is able to locally sort the branches according to the 'live' weights.

I hope all of this makes sense, because I realize the prose version is dense. However, like Fermat said, the code example is too big to fit into this margin :)

Comment: cool answer but...  Both the long[] arrays *and* the trees are dynamically produced.  Would the profiling you suggest still work in that case?  For example could I couple this with bytecode generation?

Comment: Things being dynamic makes it hard to do any predictions in general. You might get better cost/benefit from just optimizing the constant performance costs (i.e. compile to bytecode/assembly as is)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple and fast way to evaluate boolean operations like this in C. Assuming you want to evaluate z=(x op y) you can do this:

```
 z = result[op+x+(y<<1)];
```

So op will be a multiple of 4 to select your operation AND, OR, XOR, etc. you create a lookup table for all possible answers. If this table is small enough, you can encode it into a single value and use right shift and a mask to select the output bit:

```
z = (MAGIC_NUMBER >> (op+x+(y<<1))) & 1;
```

That would be the fastest way to evaluate large numbers of these. Of course you'll have to split operations with multiple inputs  into trees where each node has only 2 inputs. There is no easy way to short circuit this however. You can convert the tree into a list where each item contains the operation number and pointers to the 2 inputs and output. Once in list form, you can use a single loop to blow through that one line a million times very quickly.

For small trees, this is a win. For larger trees with short circuiting it's probably not a win because the average number of branches that need to be evaluated goes from 2 to 1.5 which is a huge win for large trees. YMMV.

**EDIT:**
On second thought, you can use something like a skip-list to implement short circuiting. Each operation (node) would include a compare value and a skip-count. if the result matched the compare value, you can bypass the next skip-count values. So the list would be created from a depth-first traversal of the tree, and the first child would include a skip count equal to the size of the other child. This takes a bit more complexity to each node evaluation but allows short circuiting. Careful implementation could do it without any condition checking (think 1 or 0 times the skip-count).

Comment: this kind of stuff makes me really miss my assembly and C days.  Sadly I'm "stuck with Java" at the moment :(  but +1 for the definitely nice answer!

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Thanks. I used this once for digital logic simulation. See the edit for short circuiting with the list ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your byte-coding idea is the right direction.
What I would do, regardless of language, is write a precompiler.
It would walk each tree, and use print statements to translate it into source code, such as.

```
((word&1) && ((word&2) || ((word&4) && (word&8))))
```

That can be compiled on the fly whenever the trees change, and the resulting byte code / dll loaded, all of which takes under a second.

The thing is, at present you are interpreting the contents of the trees.
Turning them into compiled code should make them run 10-100 times faster.

ADDED in response to your comments on not having the JDK. Then, if you can't generate Java byte code, I would try to write my own byte-code interpreter than would run as fast as possible. It could look something like this:

```
while(iop < nop){
  switch(code[iop++]){
    case BIT1: // check the 1 bit and stack a boolean
      stack[nstack++] = ((word & 1) != 0);
      break;
    case BIT2: // check the 2 bit and stack a boolean
      stack[nstack++] = ((word & 2) != 0);
      break;
    case BIT4: // check the 4 bit and stack a boolean
      stack[nstack++] = ((word & 4) != 0);
      break;
    // etc. etc.
    case AND: // pop 2 booleans and push their AND
      nstack--;
      stack[nstack-1] = (stack[nstack-1] && stack[nstack]);
      break;
    case OR: // pop 2 booleans and push their OR
      nstack--;
      stack[nstack-1] = (stack[nstack-1] || stack[nstack]);
      break;
  }
}
```

The idea is to cause the compiler to turn the switch into a jump table, so it performs each operation with the smallest number of cycles.
To generate the opcodes, you can just do a postfix walk of the tree.

On top of that, you might be able to simplify it by some manipulation of De Morgan's laws, so you could check more than one bit at a time.

Comment: ok thanks :)  Oh well then I'll try to learn the ASM bytecode library for Java and see what gives :)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: You can, but I wouldn't. I would generate source code and let the compiler generate the low-level stuff. It's plenty quick enough.

Comment: sadly I may not have full control of the JDK, if any, installed on the machines this shall run on :(

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Ok, that makes it harder. Java bytecode would be your next best bet. If you can't do that, then you might make your own interpreter, as I outlined above.

Comment: I like your edit... But I checked and the ASM library for Java seems to be only 50 KB. I don't know what's best atm.  I'll evaluate both options :)  But I think, out of facility, I'll first start with what you're suggesting in your edit :)