# Suggestions on how to create an user-friendly UI for a builder expression(if statements ,mathematical and logical operations)

Tags: user-interface

I need to create a builder expression in asp.net that allows users to create and edit expressions like this

```
If  ([age] >=60 :  50; If ([age]>=50 :  40; If ([age]>=40 : 30; If([age]>=30 : 20;0))))
```

or its more readable equivalent :

```
If  ([age] >=60 :  50) Else If ([age]>=50 : 40) Else If ([age]>=40 : 30)  Else If ([age]>=30 : 20) Else 0
```

I know how to run code on the fly and I also have a few ideas on how to convert these strings into a  .net code, the problem I'm facing now , is how to design an UI that lets users edit this sort of expressions with the minimum margin of error.
I had thought of using a dropdownlist with all the variables defined by the user , another one for the available operators, but I'm not so sure, that's why I want to ask you guys if you have ever done something similar or have any ideas on how to do this

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user interface design.

Comment: @MattBall , but why off-topic?? I have seen other questions similar to this one(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703340/how-can-i-implement-user-friendly-boolean-logic-in-a-web-form-gui) , and none of them have been considered as such!!!

Comment: @MattBall Axel is right I have also seen some questions like this and no one have ever said a word about it. BTW welcome Axel

Comment: @eddy prior existence of questions does not imply on-topic-ness. That's why we close/[lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/133242)/delete some popular questions: they set an undesirable precedent. What was once on-topic is not necessarily on-topic now. To wit: things change.